# what does it means in awk script? `awk -F "|" '{!a[$1]++}{printf RS $1}{print FS $2}' input.txt`

Tags: awk

I need meaning of below code in unix, and help me go forward..

```
`awk -F "|" '{!a[$1]++}{printf RS $1}{print FS $2}' input.txt`
```

My sample i/p file is like below

```
1|Balaji 1|Kumar 3|India 3|China 3|Australia 1|Dinesh
```

I need o/p like below

```
1|Balaji|Kumar|Dinesh 3|India|China|Australia
```

Comment: I assume that those names could have spaces. Am I right? Also, are you stuck with `awk` or would you accept more powerful languages, like `perl` or `python`?

Comment: Why? You say what you want output given that input but without knowing WHY Dinesh gets a 3 after it, Kumar gets the 3 removed from it, etc. we're just guessing and could give you a totally inappropriate answer that produces that output for that specific input but is wrong in the general case. The awk script you posted is just nonsense, by the way, so no point explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

I won't explain the awk line in your question. because it doesn't make much sense:

- created array a[], but never use
- wrong usage of RS, FS

try this one-liner:

```
awk -F'[| ]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i%2)a[$i]=a[$i]?a[$i]"|"$(i+1):$(i+1)}
END{for(x in a) printf x"|"a[x]" ";print ""}' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$ echo "1|Balaji 1|Kumar 3|India 3|China 3|Australia 1|Dinesh"|awk -F'[| ]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i%2)a[$i]=a[$i]?a[$i]"|"$(i+1):$(i+1)}END{for(x in a) printf x"|"a[x]" ";print ""}'
1|Balaji|Kumar|Dinesh 3|India|China|Australia
```

Note that there would be an ending space, it could be removed in the END loop.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, it can be change to simply. I am not sure why !a[$1]++ is written inside that.Its obsolete overe there:

```
awk -F "|" '{printf RS $1}{print FS $2}' input.txt
```

it will print first the record separator which is newline and then $1 which is the first field and then the field separator which is "|" and then the second field $2 and then a newline(since the statement is print. If printf is used newline will not be printed).

Based on your comment, below should work:

```
   awk '{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){split($i,a,"|");
                           b[a[1]]?b[a[1]]=b[a[1]]" "a[2]:b[a[1]]=a[2]
                          }
        for(j in b)printf j"|"b[j]" ";
        print"";}' your_file
```

Comment: my sample i/p file is like below
1|Balaji
1|Kumar
3|India
3|China
3|Australia
1|Dinesh

i need o/p like below
1|Balaji|Kumar|Dinesh
3|India|China|Australia

Answer (score 1):

Changing record selector makes it easy to read this data.  It have only a small bug that I do not see how to solve, it prints it on two line.

```
awk -F\| '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]"|"$2:$2} END{for(i in a) printf i"|"a[i]" "}' RS=" " file
1|Balaji|Kumar|Dinesh
 3|India|China|Australia
```

New version with correct output, thanks to Birei

```
awk -F\| '{sub(/\n/,x, $0); a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]"|"$2:$2} END{for(i in a) printf i"|"a[i]" "}' RS=" "
1|Balaji|Kumar|Dinesh 3|India|China|Australia
```

Comment: I think that when you change *Record Separator* variable (`RS`), `awk` doesn't remove last newline character, so you will need to do it manually. One way with `sub()`: `sub(/\n/, "", $0)`

Comment: There are two typos. Second field is the replacement string, should be blank in this case, and third field is the variable, I chose `$0` but could be the last one too, `$NF`. The dollar sign is needed to refer to any of them.

Comment: I did miss the `$` in `$0`, fixed.
Using `x` is a way to set it to blank, since `x` does not exist, its blank.  I could use `""`, but `x` is shorter.

Comment: It's ok. Simply the variable makes you look around twice before realize of its meaning there. Shorter but less readable.